# what is the difference in PCI "type" between these PCI cards?

Tags: pci

The PCI cards happen to be different colours, so let's call them the black one and the green one. (i'm guessing the colour is just coincidence?!).

I have an old computer that takes the green PCI card pictured.  It's a PCI  dialup modem card.  I've taken it out and photographed it as an example of what the computer takes.

I got a cheap old PCI card off ebay(PCI-USB) - the black one (I guess perhaps black is unusual too!)- but it doesn't fit.

What is the name of the specification of each of the two cards such that I can see what distinguishes them. What are they called.

I remember back in the day there being a 3.3V PCI, vs a 5V PCI, so for those i'd know ok one is called the 3.3V PCI and one is called the 5V PCI.  No doubt things have changed since then. What's the difference between the two cards pictured in terms of for example what they're called?

I can see the black one has about 7 pins on the smaller section and the green one has about 11 pins on the smaller section

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't fit? Since the small section is shorter, you might be able to fit it perfectly well just leaving some of the slot's pins unoccupied. I have no idea if that would work or not or if it would break anything mind.

Comment: @terdon well, it's a screwless case, and the card didn't fit in snugly enough for me to pull the case's thing over the card to lock the card in place. So the card didn't fit in nicely in that sense. And when I tried to pull the card out it was very stiff I was a bit worried for the computer's pci slot.

Comment: Just align the card properly. It should fit. Make sure that the bracket goes where it supposed to

Answer (score 3):

If you check Wikipedia you will find this picture:

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PCI_Keying.png)</sup>

Both your cards have a single notch.
Both notches are on the opposite site of the PCI bracket.

This makes both cards 5 volt only, 32 bit PCI cards.

Looking at the pin layout the last set of pins are for power supply or indicating that this is a 64 bit card. These seem to be missing on your card. (Specifically: +5v, +5v, ACK,REQ 64, IOPower as show in the picture below). The black card might just get enough power from the pins on the opposite side of the card, though not connecting IOPOWER is confusing. It could work if the PCI bus is pulled up or down to the right setting, so the signal does not float. And not connecting it saves material and thus costs.

Part of the PCI connector pinout
[image: Part of the PCI connector pinout]
<sup>[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI)</sup>

Comment: Both cards in his picture are regular 5V only PCI cards.

Comment: @AlexP. they may be both  5V 32-bit PCI (and not PCI-E), but the black one doesn't seem very regular to me. How often have you seen a 5V 32-bit PCI card with such a small number of pins on the smaller section (7-pins) and how often have you seen a black PCI card 5V 32-bit?  i've used lots of PCI cards. never black and with less pins on the smaller part.

Comment: "7pin" configuration is totally acceptable. It is missing some extra 5V lines.

Comment: @AlexP.  any links online for me to read about this? like article on it or people writing of using it, I googled for 7pin PCI, got nothing much.

Comment: @Hennes the green one looks old school to me. pci.  which is your pinout a pinout for? can you link to the source?

Comment: Will add a link to the source. (Wikipedia, Conventional_PCI, 1/3rd down the page).

Comment: @barlop, I don't have any links but I've seen many cards like this before. And they all worked just fine. The "shorter" card has all needed connections, fits in to the slot. The rest is up to the manufacturer.

Comment: @Hennes, the missing IOPWR lines were also redundant - so no problem there as well

Comment: @AlexP. thanks.. though I value that computer and don't want to feel like i might be breaking something in the slot when I pull the card out(it's so stiff). i'd be less worried with one that fits the whole slot. i've got to look for a UK seller that has a USB-PCI card that looks like the green card.

Comment: It's worth you adding this to make your pinout more meaningful. From wikipedia "Connector pinout:
The PCI connector is defined as having 62 contacts on each side of the edge connector, but two or four of them are replaced by key notches, so a card has 60 or 58 contacts on each side. Pin 1 is closest to the backplate. B and A sides are as follows, looking down into the motherboard connector"   "64-bit PCI extends this by an additional 32 contacts on each side which provide AD[63:32], C/BE[7:4]#, the PAR64 parity signal, and a number of power and ground pins."

Comment: and you should add a title to your pinout. as wikipedia does. "32-bit PCI connector pinout".  The smaller section is in a sense 14-pin (2*7). As it has pins each side. 2(or 4 if you include both sides), missing pins are labelled as +5V  but there are still other +5V pins.

Comment: AIUI The whole bus runs at the same voltage, and IOPWR powers the transcievers on the card to allow them to run at the correct voltage for the bus. Therefore there is no real need for the IOPWR pin on a single voltage card.