# How to tell if a PCI bus is running in 32 or 64 bit mode?

Tags: pci, bus

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/588848/what-is-the-difference-in-pci-type-between-these-pci-cards) you can read that PCI (not PCIe) cards can have 32bit or 64bit.

My motherboard MS-6340 has 3 64bit PCI slots. I've put a 32bit PCI card into the 64bit slot. AFAIK the bus is now running at 32bit and is slower (64bit is faster).

I am looking for a tool that can tell me if a PCI bus is running at 32 or 64bit.

Because I want to know if without the card the bus is running at 64bit.

I tried lspci on linux but it lists the devices and not the bus itself.

But I am also fine with a tool for Windows...

Comment: Dunno about PCI, but if you run `lspci` with enough verbosity it displays the link state for PCIe devices. Maybe something similar works with PCI. Of course, this is only meaningful if other cards are present in the bus.

Comment: What makes you think 64-bit PCI is faster? It really depends on what you're doing. The same amount of messages get transferred, but in 32-bit mode, the message are half the size. If there is nothing that needs more bandwidth than 32-bit bus width can provide, it's not going to get any faster, since the latency is exactly the same (33/66MHz)

Comment: @mtak I am not familiar with the PCI bus but if it works like a memory bus then in 64bit mode you only need 1 command while in 32 bit you need 2. The overhead is simply smaller in 64bit mode. And if 64bit wasn't faster what else should be the advantage? Why should there be a 64bit mode at all if there was no advantage?

Comment: My bad. The bus shouldn't care about what is plugged in. The bus has a frequency of either 33 or 66MHz that determines how fast it is, it is up to the card whether it talks over 32 or 64 address/data lines after that.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit card, it's likely not gonna do 64-bit transfers anyway, so what would be the speed difference? 64-bit exists for cards that need more than 32-bit address space, or do large transfers. Either way, your 32-bit card isn't going to take advantage of this.

Comment: @mtak I did read that in a forum. I now think the address size (32/64) does not affect speed. Instead the clock rate (33/66 MHz) does.

Comment: @somega Clock-speed determines the amount of data-transfers that can be made per seconds. Data-bus-width determines the # of bits in a single data-transfer. Data-bus-width x data-transfer-per-second determines bandwidth (that is what we would normally call the speed of data-flow). The size of the address-bus is not part of that calculation at all.

Comment: Lspci shows if the card uses 32 or 64bit. And it seems the bus can have both types at the same time.